# Write a java client to test spring mvc multipart request

Tags: spring

I have written a spring controller to handle a multipart request and upload a csv file. How can be a client be written in java to test this controller?

I need to invoke the url i have mapped to the controller but what should i sent in the payload (a csv file or string with comma separated text and send a contentType in header).

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) command from command line, you don't need to write a java client.

Sample

```
curl -F "file=@localfile;filename=nameinpost" www.myhost.com
```